# How to install MinGW correctly on Windows

Tags: c++, mingw

I have recently started learning C++, but I require a compiler. I have tried the one packaged with [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks), but I have been told it is out of date.

I have tried reading the instructions on the website, but I simply don't know which files to download and un-zip. Is there a list of files to download? (latest version) and a folder structure I need?

Comment: Visual C++ express edition is free. In case you're interesting check out http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was the person that pointed you at the more up-to-date version at Twilight Dragon. The file you want there is http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-MinGW%20Installer/1.908.0/tdm-mingw-1.908.0-4.4.1-2.exe/download which is a Windows binary installer - you just run it. Note that you don't actually *need* to do this - the version that comes with Code::Blocks will work OK for someone starting to learn C++.

Comment: Yes, awfully sorry about this, I should have checked my previous question :( I ended up using this one, thanks!

Comment: @Neil: Does that version finally support Unicode or is it plagued by the problems the official MinGW has?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a pre-packaged MinGW that includes some common APIs like Boost, SDL etc: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

If I remember correctly, the only thing you must do to get it working is to modify Windows's PATH environment variable.

edit: OpenAL is not included in this package.

Comment: This is great. More people should know this distribution! +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [some instructions](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/HOWTO-for-building-octave-using-mingw-msys-td1650410.html#a1650415) to have a MinGW setup that I used to build [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) modules.

I have switched to using the build environment for msysgit. Just download the [netinstall](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) file and it will setup GCC, [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), etc. along with [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).